# RxJava2 and Retrofit2 : Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, github-api, rx-android

I have been trying out how to work with *RxJava2* and *Retrofit 2* to use Github API. Trying to access the link : 
`<https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:ruby+topic:rails>`.I want to display the **NAME** and **NODE_ID**. But Have been stuck with the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ .

Here is the **Client class** for **Retrofit**.

```
    public class Client {
public static final String GITHUB_BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/search/";
private static Client instance;
private static GetData data;
public Client() {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.
            LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(GITHUB_BASE_URL).
            addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
    data = retrofit.create(GetData.class);
}
public static Client getInstance(){
    if(instance==null)
        instance = new Client();
    return  instance;
}

public Observable<List<itemsClass>> getAllUsers(){
    return data.getAllUsers();
}
```

The **interface**

```
    @GET("repositories?q=topic:ruby+topic:rails")
Observable<List<itemsClass>> getAllUsers();
```

The data I need to get through the call are like this:

```
    {
     "total_count": 2997,
     "incomplete_results": false,
     "items": [
          {
              "id": 8514,
              "name": "rails",
               "owner": {  
                     "node_id": "MDEyOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjQyMjM=" 
                        },
             }],
     },......
```

And also the **MainActivity** from where I will display the data.

```
    subscription = Client.getInstance().getAllUsers().
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.
            mainThread()).subscribe(new Observer<List<ParentClass>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG,"In completed()");
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"In onError()");
            Log.d(TAG,""+e);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNext(List<ParentClass> parentClasses) {
            Log.d(TAG,"In onNext()");
            loadData(parentClasses);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you get isn't an array. 
 
When using json converters (in your case it's gson), the response must match exactly to the POJO.

You can wrap `itemClass` with another class like `responseClass` which will have:

```
class responseClass {
    int total_count;
    boolean incomplete_results;
    List<itemClass> items;
}
```

And then, in Client interface:

```
@GET("repositories?q=topic:ruby+topic:rails")
Observable<responseClass> getAllUsers();
```

---

Another option is not to use the auto converter, instead you may do:

```
@GET("repositories?q=topic:ruby+topic:rails")
Observable<JsonObject> getAllUsers();  //com.google.gson.JsonObject
```

and then convert only the items array with gson.

```
Type typeToken = new TypeToken<List<itemClass>>() {}.getType();
List<itemClass> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.get("items"), typeToken);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue has nothing to do with RxJava. It's problem with your data model:

`Observable<List<itemsClass>>` - you are expecting list of entities to come, but in fact your json is entity that has fields `total_count`, `incomplete_results` and actual list field `items` of (apparently) `itemsClass`. Please use correct model under `Observable<...> getAllUsers();` interface method.